# firebug console

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, firebug

The following is my block of code. since I haven't installed **Firebug** in IE, Every time when  I try to test my code in `IE` I'm getting an error message **console** is undefined. so I decided and developed this block of code, so that `console.log` work only in firefox and to avoid error messages in **IE**.

```
function clog() {
    if(window.console && window.console.firebug) {
        var a =[];
        for(var i=0;i<arguments.length;i++) {
            a.push(arguments[i]);
        }
        console.log(a.join(' , '));
    }
}
```

my code is working fine and  I'm getting the results  which I wanted,

but when I tried to  use the above code on jQuery ( for example `clog($('body'));` ),

the result which I expected is to be  `jQuery(body)` . but  I'm getting the result as `[object Object]`

How can I get The results which I expected  ?

Thank you !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
console.log(a);
```

instead of

```
console.log(a.join(' , '));
```

should do it.

`Array.prototype.join` will concatenate all array entrys into a `String`. That means

```
var b = [{}, "test"];
b.toString()
```

will evaluate to `"[object Object],test"` regardless what `methods` or `members` are within that object. You just lose that information calling `.toString()`.

Answer (score 4):

When you call a selector like that, say `$('body')` what you're doing is creating an object, a jQuery object...so your output is correct.

If you want to display something other than it's `.toString()`, then you should call that property, for example:

```
$('body').selector //body
$('body').length   //1
$('body').context  //document
```

---

If all you're using is `console.log`, I find just creating it if it's missing (as opposed to checking whenever you want to use it) is much easier, just have this run before any of your logging code:

```
if (typeof console == "undefined") console = { log: function () { } };
```

Then you can remove your current `if` check.

Comment: To be more correct: it's called a JavaScript object, not a jQuery object. ;)

Comment: @Marcel - it's both...it's literally an instance of a jQuery object, like an Array is a JavaScript object, but *specifically* it's an Array :)

Comment: Why doesn't `if(window.console)` work correctly? It will evaluate to `false` if `console` is not available.

Comment: @Marcel - Not in IE...had this issue yesterday, don't ask me why, even in IE8 this still breaks, haven't tested in 9 though.

Comment: Ah, jQuery extends the default object? I'm not a jQuery expert, I merely thought it returned the `getElementById` object.

Comment: So `if(window.XMLHttpRequest)` will also cause an error in IE? I've seen this kind of code in many places (and used it myself, too).

Comment: @Marcel - It's internally an Array, that represents the DOM elements the selector found (or were added, in the chain etc), so it doesn't contain the objects, but an array of references to the DOM elements, any action you perform gets applied to all of them, e.g. `$(".myClass").fadeOut()` would fade out *all* `class="myClass"` elements the selector found.

Comment: @Nick: did you try (just to be sure) to use `if('console' in window)` instead of `if(window.console)` in IE ?

Comment: @jAndy - I'm double checking now, it seems compatibility view screws with this too, I'm not sure why here.

Comment: @jAndy - Compatibility mode breaks `if(!window.console)` here but not in a simple test...time to write a fun email to a plugin author screwing with my console definition.

Answer (score 3):

I always write a wrapper function (to keep non 'console' browers from having problem)

```
function log(msg) {
    try {
      console.log(msg);
    } catch(e){}
}
```

You could examine the "msg" object, then check the type to determine whether it's a "jQuery" object, and extract the data.